# comparing $k$ minimum of a sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, foundations

Let $a_i, b_j \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $ 1 \leq i, j \leq n$. Suppose $a_i \leq b_i$ for any $i$. Define $$\alpha _ 1 = \min(a_1, \ldots, a_n), \ \beta_1 = \min (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$$ and

$$\alpha_i = \min \{(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \cdots - \alpha_{i-1}\}, \\ \beta_i = \min \{(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n) - \beta_1 - \beta_2 - \cdots - \beta_{i-1}\}$$

for all $2 \leq i \leq n,$ where $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) - a_i = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}, \ldots, a_n)\ $ for any $1 \leq i \leq n.$
Then $$\alpha_i \leq \beta_i$$ for any $i$.

Roughly, it is the comparison of the $i$ minimum of $(a_i), (b_j).$

I try to prove by induction. The basis step is clear : $\alpha_1 = \min (a_i) \leq b_j$ for any $j$. So $\alpha_1 \leq \beta_1$

Inductive step : Assume $\alpha_i \leq \beta_i$ for any $i \leq k$. I will show that $\alpha_{k+1} \leq \beta_{k+1}.$

Try both direct proof and contradiction proof (cannot reach contradiction), but I cannot finish the argument.

Any help please ?

Comment: Since you proved the case $\alpha_1\leq\beta_1$ for arbitrary $n$, doesn't the case $\alpha_2\leq \beta_2$, follow with $n$ replaced by $n-1$ and the same argument?

Comment: I think it might be more complicated. For example, assume $\alpha_1 = a_1$ and $\beta_1 = b_3$. Then we left with $a_2, a_3, ..., a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, b_4, ... b_n$. Well I do not know the relation of $a_3$ and $b_1$. In the basis step, I know $a_i \leq b_i$ for any $i$, so $\alpha_1 \leq a_i \leq b_i$ ,and since $\beta_1$ is one of $b_i$ so I am done. But now I dont have information about $a_3$ and $b_1$.

Comment: $a_1\leq a_3 \leq b_3 \leq b_1$. First follows from $\alpha_1=a_1\leq a_i$, second is given $a_3\leq b_3$ in problem, third follows from $\beta_1=b_3\leq b_i$

Comment: Oh I see, $a_1 < a_3 < b_3 < b_1 $. Okay for $\alpha_2 \leq \beta_2$. Then I think the argument will go more sophisticated, for example, $k=3$. Now assume $\alpha_1 = a_1, \alpha_2 = a_5, \beta_1 = b_3, \beta_2 = b_6$, now $a_3, a_6, b_1, b_5$ are left to detemine their relationship.

Comment: I think I get some ideas of why the statement is true, and how the proof might proceed. But it just hard to translate it into rigourous proof langauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something slightly informal:

So w.l.o.g. take $\alpha_1=a_1.\quad$  (otherwise one could relabel)

If $\beta_1=b_1$, then by applying the same argument as you did with $n$ replaced by $n-1$, (with renaming or relabelling if you wish), on the sets $\{a_2,\ldots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_2,\ldots, b_n\}$.

It follows that $\alpha_i\leq\beta_i$.

Now if $\beta_1\neq b_1$, say w.l.o.g. $\beta_1=b_2$, then notice that:

$a_1=\alpha_1\leq a_2\leq b_2 =\beta_1\leq b_1$,

thus we have in the new sets $\{a_2,\ldots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,b_3,\ldots,b_n\}$ that for $i\geq 3$, $a_i\leq b_i$, and also $a_2\leq b_1$.

We can then simply relabel these sets as $\{a'_1,\ldots, a'_{n-1}\}$ and $\{b'_1,b'_2,\ldots,b'_{n-1}\}$ in the obvious way, and again apply the same argument.